# implementing Python OLAP cube with multiple storage

Tags: python, olap, olap-cube

I have two tables **in two different databases** as shown below. I want to implement this scenario using

Python OLAP cube to get the below mentioned output.

```
DB1

Table name: Customer_details    

id name 

1 abc 

2 xyz 

DB 2 

Table Name : Bills

id  Customer_id   amount 

1   1             500 

2   1             600 

3   2             300 

Output 

Name     Amount 

abc      1100

xyz      300
```

Below is some code I'm using to solve it:

```
{
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "name":"customer_details",
            "levels":[
                {
                   "name":"customer",
                    "label":"Customer",
                    "attributes": ["id","name"]     
                }

            ]

        }
    ],
    "cubes": [
        {
            "name": "bills",
            "dimensions": ["customer_details"],
            "measures": [
                {"name":"amount", "label":"Total"}
            ],
            "aggregates": [ 
                    {
                        "name": "total",
                        "function": "sum",
                        "measure": "amount"
                    }
                ],
            "joins":[
                {"master":"bills.customer_id", "detail":"customer_details.id"}                
            ],
            "mappings": {
                "name": "customer_details.name"                
            }
        }
    ]
}




workspace = Workspace()
workspace.register_store("store1", "sql", url="postgresql://...")
workspace.register_store("store2", "sql", url="postgresql://...")

workspace.import_model("model.json"), store="store1", namespace="default")
workspace.import_model("model.json"), store="store2", namespace="default")

browser = workspace.browser("bills")
cubeData = browser.aggregate(drilldown=["customer_details"])
```

I get the error no such table customer_details

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have written over there that the table name is

```
Table name: Customer_details
```

And for the dimensions you have written in your model.json

```
  .."name":"customer_details",   ...
```

Large and lower case could solve your problem..